# error trying to analyse with Error on MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I’m trying to run C# Code Analysis on jenkins but always get this error

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: 1:
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe:
 MZ����@���: not found 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: 1: 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: ��kO����j: not found 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: 22: 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: ��V�0N Jl �@ ���.rsrc��P@@.reloc�X@B,lH,�2,�^�@j�0}s �~rp�)%rp�(7s o ~rp�)%r-p�(8s o ~~ o ~~ o *0�-r5ps z-rUps zQ~s o ( _�( o o (  (! _�i(_,=�%�%�s: File name too long 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: 23: 
 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_for_MSBuild_2.0/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") 
 ERROR: Execution of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild failed (exit code 2) Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: There are encoding issues in the code you pasted. Can you please fix this?

Comment: that's the problem, always shows those symbols and we don't know how to view a clear log.

Comment: We try to run through the console, the same process and says this

`MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:TEST_INDIVIDUAL /n:TEST /v:1.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.xxxxx.com.co:9000/

bash: MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe: command not found`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to execute a Windows binary (a ".exe" file) on a Unix like operating system. No wonder why this can not work.

If you want to build .NET solution using the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins and the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild, then you must explicitly configure the job to get executed on a Windows machine.